# Conversão de bases numéricas com JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Como montar uma tabela com JavaScript para mostrar números decimais, binários, octal e hexadecimal.

```
For (var i=0;  i <=<?php echo $num ?> ; i++){
   ......................
}

document.write ....
```

A variável `$num` é obtida via post de um formulário

Resultado esperado

```
_________________________________________
Decimal  |   Hex  |   Octal   |   Binário
   0     |    0   |     0     |      0
   1     |    1   |     1     |      1
   2     |    2   |     2     |     10
```

e sucessivamente.

Comment: Você poderia explicar melhor sua pergunta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O método toString( ) está disponível em todas as versões de todos os navegadores e
aceita um parâmetro base.

Se definirmos esse parâmetro base entre 2 e 16, podemos converter números para os equivalentes em string nas diferentes bases numéricas.

```js
var content = "" 
for (var i = 0; i <= 5 ; i++) { 
content += "<TR>" 
content += "<TD>" + i.toString(10) + "</TD>" 
content += "<TD>" + i.toString(16) + "</TD>" 
content += "<TD>" + i.toString(8) + "</TD>" 
content += "<TD>" + i.toString(2) + "</TD></TR>" 
} 
document.write("<table><th>Decimal</th><th>Hexadecimal</th><th>Octal</th><th>Binário</th></tr>"+content+"</table>")
```

> você deve substituir no código acima o   `for (var i = 0; i <= 5 ; i++) {`
>
> por  `For (var i=0;  i <=<?php echo $num ?> ; i++){`

Fonte: JavaScript a Bíblia.